# MySQL populate new column with incrementing values without auto_increment

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I see lots of almost similar questions with obvious answers but I'm fairly sure this question isn't already on here.

I need to add an auto-incrementing id column to an existing table and set it as the primary key. I can't lose any of the existing data.

I can successfully make the change to the table structure but I get an error about truncated data in the new column. When I view the data every value in the new auto-incrementing column is null (and therefore not unique).

How can I back-fill these values to ensure uniqueness in my primary key?

***I would prefer to avoid dumping the existing data to a temporary table and re-inserting if there is a simpler solution.

Current script:

```
alter table the_table add new_field int first;
alter table the_table drop primary key, add primary key (new_field);
alter table the_table change new_field new_field int unsigned not null auto_increment;
```

I run the script in this order as I can't have an auto-incrementing column that isn't the primary key.

(MySQL 5.3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try creating the column, setting it as primary key and auto increment in one go

```
ALTER TABLE `the_table` ADD `new_field` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this results in "SQL Error (1068): Multiple primary key defined"

Comment: @tomfumb I just gave you the create statement, you surely have to drop the previous primary key.

Comment: Add the SQL "SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;" before that one, if you want the auto increase step=1.

Comment: I want to add to ybdesire's note (and give credit as well).   The final query that worked for me on MySQL 5.0 using PHPmyAdmin 4.5.4:   

SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
ALTER TABLE my_table_name ADD my_table_field INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

And it worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Just add an auto-increment field, without being a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE `the_table` ADD `new_field` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: MySQL does not allow an auto_increment column that is not the primary key